# How to remove dynamically generated fields from div level?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My concept is to create maximum 20 blocks( it contains some input field) on button click "Add", If you tap on "Add" button then new block could be added, that was successfully done. Now i want to remove the block which is created on "Add" button click.

Eg: If user is create 5 block by using in "ADD" button. If user taps on "Minus" button, in Block 2, then Block 2 should be removed from the list and count of the block should be updated correspondingly.[image]
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FADO51NINJMD

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#commentForm").validate();
        });
        function add()
        {   
            var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            var label = document.createElement('label');
            label.innerHTML = '<h5 class="label">Block '+i+'<input type="button" value="Minus" onclick="minus()"></h5>';
            divtest.appendChild(label);
            var length = $('#Length').clone().attr('id', 'Length' + i).attr('name', 'Length' + i);
            var attribute = $('#Attribute').clone().attr('id', 'Attribute' + i).attr('name', 'Attribute' + i);
            var column = $('#Column').clone().attr('id', 'Column' + i).attr('name', 'Column' + i);
            length.appendTo(divtest);
            attribute.appendTo(divtest);
            column.appendTo(divtest);
            objTo.appendChild(divtest);
            i++
        }

        function minus()
        {   
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="commentForm" method="post" action="">
        <div id="room_fileds">
       Static Field
            <input type="text" name="Length" maxlength="2" id="Length" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" placeholder="Field 1 Length"  class="form-control required">
             <input type="text" name="Attribute" id="Attribute"  placeholder="Field 1 Attribute" class="form-control" required>
              <select name="Column" id="Column" class="required" >
              <option selected  value="">Field Column </option>
              <option value="1">YES</option>
              <option value="2">NO</option>
              </select>
              </div>
              <br><br>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit1">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is php tagget in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `id` while creating `div` node

```
divtest.setAttribute("id", "div" + i);
```

For `minus function` pass created `id` number in `onclick`

```
label.innerHTML = '<h5 class="label">Block '+i+'<input type="button" onclick="minus('+i+')" value="Minus"></h5>';
```

And set `minus function` as

```
function minus(_id)
{
    var _div_id = "div" + _id;
    var _div_elem = document.getElementById(_div_id);
    _div_elem.parentNode.removeChild(_div_elem);
}
```

```js
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
 //$("#commentForm").validate();
});
function add()
{   
 var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
 var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.setAttribute("id","div" + i);
    
 var label = document.createElement('label');
 label.innerHTML = '<h5 class="label">Block '+i+'<input type="button" onclick="minus('+i+')" value="Minus"></h5>';
    
 divtest.appendChild(label);
 var length = $('#Length').clone().attr('id', 'Length' + i).attr('name', 'Length' + i);
 var attribute = $('#Attribute').clone().attr('id', 'Attribute' + i).attr('name', 'Attribute' + i);
 var column = $('#Column').clone().attr('id', 'Column' + i).attr('name', 'Column' + i);
 
 length.appendTo(divtest);
 attribute.appendTo(divtest);
 column.appendTo(divtest);
 objTo.appendChild(divtest);
 i++
}
   
function minus(_id)
{
 var _div_id = "div" + _id;
 var _div_elem = document.getElementById(_div_id);
 _div_elem.parentNode.removeChild(_div_elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="commentForm" method="post" action="">
  <div id="room_fileds">Static Field
   <input type="text" name="Length" maxlength="2" id="Length" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" placeholder="Field 1 Length"  class="form-control required">
   <input type="text" name="Attribute" id="Attribute"  placeholder="Field 1 Attribute" class="form-control" required>
   <select name="Column" id="Column" class="required" >
    <option selected  value="">Field Column </option>
    <option value="1">YES</option>
    <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select> 
   </div><br><br>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit1">
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the label parent on click. See the minus function content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#commentForm").validate();
        });
        function add()
        {   
            var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            var label = document.createElement('label');
            label.innerHTML = '<h5 class="label">Block '+i+'<input type="button" value="Minus" onclick="minus()"></h5>';
            divtest.appendChild(label);
            var length = $('#Length').clone().attr('id', 'Length' + i).attr('name', 'Length' + i);
            var attribute = $('#Attribute').clone().attr('id', 'Attribute' + i).attr('name', 'Attribute' + i);
            var column = $('#Column').clone().attr('id', 'Column' + i).attr('name', 'Column' + i);
            length.appendTo(divtest);
            attribute.appendTo(divtest);
            column.appendTo(divtest);
            objTo.appendChild(divtest);
            i++
        }

        function minus()
        {   
            //This is the clicked label, so we remove the parent (the div)
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="commentForm" method="post" action="">
        <div id="room_fileds">
       Static Field
            <input type="text" name="Length" maxlength="2" id="Length" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" placeholder="Field 1 Length"  class="form-control required">
             <input type="text" name="Attribute" id="Attribute"  placeholder="Field 1 Attribute" class="form-control" required>
              <select name="Column" id="Column" class="required" >
              <option selected  value="">Field Column </option>
              <option value="1">YES</option>
              <option value="2">NO</option>
              </select>
              </div>
              <br><br>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit1">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="removePhoneDiv">
    <input type="button" value="Add Text Field" id="add_button" >
      <ul style="list-style:none;"  id="phoneNumberList">
          <li class='Textbox1' style="float:left;width:100%;">
              <div style=" margin-top: 2%; " class='form-group' id='answerdiv'>
                   <input type='text' class='input_phone  form-control1'>
                       <img style="float:left;" src="images/close.png" class="remove_phone_number">
               </div>
           </li>
     </ul>
</div>

 <script>

                                var wrapper = $(".form-group");

                                $("#add_button").click(function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $("#phoneNumberList").append("<li class='Textbox1'><div class='form-group' id='answerdiv'><input type='text' class='form-control1' ><img  src=\"images/close.png\" class=\"remove_phone_number\"></div></li>");
                                });

                                $(".removePhoneDiv").on("click", ".remove_phone_number", function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $(this).parent('div').parent('li').remove();
                                })
                            </script>
```